# Nexus 4 factory image restore

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Hey I've download the factory image but i can't open the folder it's just gave me an unknown type file and i really need to open the folder to use the flash command [image: here is the file]

Comment: Why use winRAR when 7-zip exists?

Answer (score 2):

The image shows that you have downloaded the factory image archive, but it's not the official one. I'd suggest that you read the instructions on the official page, [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#instructions) and download the archive from there. This includes the tools needed to flash the image.

- Download the Android SDK which contains the necessary tools [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- You need to have `fastboot` in your path
- Put your device into fastboot mode with the bootloader unlocked and connected to a PC
- Extract the downloaded archive to a directory
- You should see the following files:

  - bootloader-mako-makoz30d.img
  - flash-all.bat
  - flash-all.sh
  - flash-base.sh
  - image-occam-kot49h.zip
  - radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.98.img
- Run the `flash-all.bat` file with Administrator privileges (i.e. right-click and `Run as Administrator...`)

The process will flash your device with the stock ROM, assuming the previous steps were done correctly.